# How to Limit the Maximum Size of Kernel CoreDump?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, coredump

I am running **CentOS-6** and the system got a kernel panic then rebooted.

I have enabled coredump generation, hence it generated a kernel core dump of size 500MB.

What could be the maximum size of the kernel core dump in worst case scenario?

Is there any way I could limit the size of kernel core dump.  Will `ulimit -c` limit the kernel core dump size also?

Is there any configuration available for `makedumpfile` utility to truncate the kernel core dump if its value is greater than 300MB?

Comment: This post is alittle old and better suited for [unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) stack.  If still interested though, here is a [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kdump) for setting up `kdump` which will be what you need.